# Why assignment inside test parameter in java didnt work?

Tags: java

```
int x;
if(x = 10){
    //code here
}
```

In java, this won't work, in c++ this will work.

I notice that in c++ anything you put in the test parenthesis other than false, NULL, or 0 is considered true.

example:

```
boolean x = false;
if(x){
    //code here
}

int x = 0;
if(x){
    //code here
}

if(NULL){
    //code here
}

int x; //uninitalized variable which is null
if(){
    //code here
}
```

Why in java this is not possible?? what other languages that didn't allow this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason that

```
if (x = 10) {
    // ...
}
```

isn't allowed in Java is that `x = 10` is an expression of integer type, and Java only allows boolean expressions for if conditions.  In C++, an integer is allowed as the if condition.  One big reason for this is to maintain compatibility with C - in C, there is no boolean type, so integers are perfectly valid if conditions.

You may ask: Why does Java disallow integers as if conditions?  One very important reason to do this is to stop a common bug.  It's common to write

```
if (x = 10)
```

while actually meaning

```
if (x == 10)
```

In fact, this is so common that many C/C++ programmers write

```
if (10 == x)
```

instead, just so it's harder to write an accidental assignment.

If you really do mean to perform an assignment, you can always write

```
x = 10;
// ...
```

because `x = 10` is always nonzero and thus the C++ version will always enter the if.  This way, you don't really lose expressiveness but do prevent a bug.

---

Also, you write

```
int x; //uninitalized variable which is null
if () {
    // ...
}
```

I think you mean to write `if (x)`, but that's beside the point.  An uninitialized variable is **NOT** null in C, C++, or Java!  Java doesn't allow you to use an uninitialized local (and fields are automatically initialized), so you can never use an uninitialized variable in Java.  In C/C++, an uninitialized variable *may* be null, but there is no guarantee whatsoever of that.  Instead, the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined, and is likely whatever previously executed code left on the stack.  **DO NOT** depend on an uninitialized variable being null - it will absolutely come back to bite you.

Answer (score 0):

Java differs from C/C++ in that the typing is stricter. Test conditions require boolean expressions. Integer expressions are not automatically promoted to boolean expressions.

Assignments inside comparators are still allowed, for example this will work:

```
if (x = (1 == 1))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: so in your example x must be boolean

Comment: Correct. All that is required is that the if clause is a boolean expression.

Comment: @Jonathan This is still a silly example.  It's much better to fold `1 == 1` into the literal `true`, and then to remove the if line altogether (keeping the assignment, of course) because the code inside the if will always be executed.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has different rules for truth evaluation than Java.  See this for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/

Answer (score 0):

Because it often lead to errors.

People wanted to write (x == 10) but wrote (x = 0). In your case

```
if (x = 10)
```

why do you need an if at all? It only makes sense if the RHS can be 0, so let's consider

```
if (x = b)
```

which can be 0/false in C. In Java you have to write

```
x = b;
if (x != 0)
```

I can live without it. Sometimes I miss the shortness, but I sometimes the compiler stops me, and I don't know, how many time I would have spend in searching the error. It's really a common error - similar to `(str == "foo")` instead of `(str.equals (foo))`. Easy to understand, but people make the error although.